# Assume that two sets are everywhere dense (or dense, simply), is the union of them everywhere dense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, real-numbers

Define $\lambda(x)$ as a piecewise function, where $$\lambda(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 
0, & x \in \mathbb{R}{\text{\\}}\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$ I was able to prove that, $\mathbb{Q}$ is everywhere dense (or dense), as if we let $\lambda(r_1) = \lambda(r_2) = 1$, and $r_1 < r_2$, then there exists $\displaystyle {{r_1 + r_2} \over {2}}$ such that $${1\over 2}r_1 + {1\over 2}r_1 < {1\over 2}r_2 + {1\over 2}r_1 < {1\over 2}r_2 + {1\over 2}r_2$$
We also point out that the addition of any two rationls is rational due to closure under addition for $\mathbf{Q}$, and therefore $\mathbf{Q}(r_1 + q)$ is also, for any $q$ unless $q$ is irrational (which will be important in the next proof), and therefore the middle term in the inequality is rational. (Yes, fancy field extensions to prove a simple point... I got too excited reading my algebra books, I like maths, can't help it!). Also, you may consider that if $r' + q = r'$, assuming both $r$ and $r'$ are rational, and $q$ is not, then $q = r' + r'$ which is rational, if the field extension is unnecessarily complicated.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
It is also true for $\lambda(q_1) = \lambda(q_2) = 0$, then similarly to the proof above, $\displaystyle {{q_1 + q_2} \over {2}}$ is between both other terms if we let $q_1 < q_2$, but then notice that $+(q_1,q_2)$ cannot be rational if at least one of the terms in the addition function is irrational as noted in the above proof. (And as a reminder that it is a function, I changed the notation a little bit for addition.)
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Now, these are my two proofs, perhaps naïve, perhaps wrong, or perhaps (hopefully) correct. I want to complete my proof by reaching the conclusion that the union of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}{\text{\\}}\mathbb{Q}$ is also everywhere dense (or simply, dense). Now, is there a general theorem that says, something along the lines of the union of every subset of two dense sets is also dense (assuming their closure is)? I think I know how to construct the proof if so, but I know too little analysis to attempt to open a topology book, and so any hints, or perhaps solutions, or near theorems (or lemmas) are more than welcome. (Please, if you're going to answer it, don't post a special solution to this case of rationals and irrationals, I'm looking for a general theorem, if there isn't, then do please post the general solution, and thank you in advance if you do so!)

Context: I was reading through my real analysis book and wanted to challenge myself to try to prove general theorems, like $\mathbb{R}$ being everywhere dense (or dense, simply). Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: What do you mean by trying to prove $\mathbb{R}$ is dense? Every set is dense in itself... so $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor I'm assuming we don't know that...

Comment: Well, it comes from the definition. A set $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ if its closure is $\mathbb{R}$.  The closure of $A$ by definition is $A \cup A'$ where $A'$ is the set of accumulation points of $A$... so, $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{R}' = \mathbb{R}$. Do you see why?  Or, are you using a different definition of 'dense'?

Comment: @JairTaylor Sorry for my lack of knowledge of topology, I only know so little through the abstract algebra that I learned on my own. What is the "accumulation of points" exactly here?

Comment: No worries! What's the definition of "dense" you are using?

Comment: The author of the analysis book says that if for any $a,b$ it is true that there is a $c$ such that $a < c < b$, then it is everywhere dense (or dense, simply). This of course is assuming a structure which is an ordered field, and I'm not sure what a topological space would be classified as. I read online a bit, and it's said that a subset of some topological space is called *dense* (for any point in it [the space]) if the closure of the space is the subset itself.  I intuitively understand as, there exists a density of the space as the least cardinal of a subset of it.

Comment: @JairTaylor (I mentioned you here, since there is space to do so in the comment above...)

Comment: I see now - there is a very different definition of "dense" for ordered sets that's not equivalent to the topological definition of "dense". See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order). Maybe you should edit your post to clarify.

Comment: @JairTaylor Which exactly? I see all the ones I listed as equivalent.. (at least, the first, and the last). (Also, I'll probably then remove the general-topology tag.)